# reusing a method with custom behaviour

Tags: java

I have a common method which performs file read. The method is called by 4 different callers.

The requirement is to throw a different error message based on the caller if the file size exceeds a certain number of entries. One way I can think of is to take the size limit exceeded handler from the caller.

Something like below,

```
public void readFromFile(File file,OnEntriesExceed onEntriesExceed) 
    //Method read a file line by line{
      if(the number of lines exceeds )//read line by line
          OnEntriesExceed.handle(totalNumberOfLines);        
          //calling the specific handler.
```

Now the callers can call the methods as below

caller1:

```
readFromFile(f1,(totalNumberOfLines)-> {throw new RuntimeException("entries limit exceeded in some case ")})
```

caller2:

```
readFromFile(f2,(totalNumberOfLines)-> {throw new RuntimeException("entries limit exceeded in some other case "});
```

caller3:

```
readFromFile(f3,(totalNumberOfLines)-> {throw new RuntimeException("entries limit exceeded in some case 1")})
```

caller4:

```
readFromFile(f4,(totalNumberOfLines)-> {throw new RuntimeException("entries limit exceeded in some other case 2"});
```

Are there any other best practices in java that I can implement in this case?

Comment: Yes: ignore the caller in your method and throw one type of exception, and let the caller handle anything caller-specific if they want

Comment: Thanks.Erwin Bolwidth. The approach looks nice.